# How to make Sb3 to exe

Tags: exe, mit-scratch

How can I convert a sb3 file into an exe?

I've made a game on scratch and I want to upload it as an exe. I tried searching tutorials on YouTube but most tutorials want me to download some software (Which I don't like using since it could contain viruses) and most of them are complex, so is there a way which is simple?